# Confused about how to add to a linked list stuct which is within another struct

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

I want to add nodes to the linked list of the stuct which is within another struct.

My code:

```
 struct Courses{
        char *courseName;
        int creditValue;
        Courses *next;
    };Courses;

struct Student{
        char *name;
        int age;
        Courses *list;  //First course (node)
    }Student;
```

Now I am not sure how to add course nodes through the student struct for the various courses (nodes) that need to be added to the list.

Can someone show me how this can be done?

Comment: The new course needs to be in some special position (say last, first,...)?

Comment: @dubafek The list hasn't been filled with anything yet. So the first course would be the first node and every other course after that will be connected to the previous one.

Comment: Doesn't matter that the list is inside the Student struct. The code for adding a node is the same as it would be for any other linked list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a function which adds one node to your list at head:

```
 struct Courses{
     char *courseName;
     int creditValue;
     struct Courses *next;
  };

  struct Student{
      char *name;
      int age;
      struct Courses *list;
  };

  void addNodeAtHead( struct Student *student, struct Courses *newNode )
  {
      newNode->next = student->list; // successor of newNode is head of list
      student->list = newNode;       // new head of list is newNode
  }
```

This is a function which adds one node to your list at tail:

```
  void addNodeAtTail( struct Student *student, struct Courses *newNode )
  {
      newNode->next = NULL;           // sucessor of newNode is NULL, because newNode becomes tail of list
      if ( student->list == NULL )
          student->list = newNode;    // if list is empty, newNode will be head of list
      else
      {
          struct Courses *temp = student->list;
          while( temp->next != NULL ) // search last element in list
              temp = temp->next;
          temp->next = newNode;       // successor of last node is newNode
      }
  }
```

Note if you create a new list you have to initialize the structure element `list` of `struct Student` with `NULL`.

```
void addCourse( struct Student *s, const char* courseName, int creditValue )
{
    struct Courses *course = malloc( sizeof( Courses ) ); 
    course->courseName = malloc( strlen(courseName)+1 );
    strcpy( course->courseName, courseName );
    course->creditValue = creditValue;
    addNodeAtTail( student, course );
}

struct Student *student = malloc( sizeof( Student) );
student->list = NULL;
....

addCourse( student, "course", 666 );
```

How to print the list:

```
void printList( struct Student *student )
{
      struct Courses *temp = student->list;
      while( temp != NULL )
      {
          printf( "courseName: %s, creditValue %d\n", courseName, creditValue );
          temp = temp->next;
      }
}
```

Comment: I want to always add to tail. So if the list is empty I would add to tail, but since the list is empty the node would be first node and every node after that would be added to the tail. If I wanted to adopt this procedure I would use your second function "addNodeAtTail" all the time right? I would never have to use "addNodeAtHead" right? Even if the list was empty and I wanted to add the first node, if I use "addNodeAtTail" it would still work right?

Comment: One doubt about your code. When you do "newNode->next=NULL" is this correct? Shouldnt it have "student->list" before it because you are accessing courses struct through the student struct?

Comment: Thank you for you help. I just have one more question, is there a way I can print all the nodes in "Course *list" from the Student struct? I know how to print directly from course struct, but I want to know how to print the entire list from Student Struct.

Answer (score 0):

a few errors in your codes and the previous answer. I think you want to define a struct called Courses.You just do things like

```
struct Courses{
    char *courseName;
    int creditValue;
    Courses *next;
};
```

if you do not want to type struct Course for every instance of variable. just add

```
typedef struct Courses Courses;
```

same for student struct.

```
struct Student{
  char *name;
  int age;
  Courses *list;  //First course (node)
};
```

First of all, you should initialize your struct variable with a user defined function, which gives the struct student variable name,age and sets pointer to NULL.

for example

```
void init(struct Student* s, char * name, int age ){
  s->age = age;
  s->name = malloc(strlen(name) + 1);
  strcpy(s->name,name);
  s->list = NULL;
 }
```

if you want to define a add_course function
here is example

```
 void add_course(struct Student*s, char* course_name,int credit){
      struct Courses* c = malloc(sizeof (struct Courses) );
      c->courseName = course_name;
      c->creditValue = credit;
      c->next = NULL;

      if (s->list == NULL)
            s->list = c;
      else{
            while (s->list->next != NULL)
                  s->list->next = s->list->next->next;

            s->list->next = c;
       }
 }
```

then write a function to clean up resources allocated by malloc()

I think you are new to C. If you want to run my codes please include necessary libraries like

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include<stdlib.h> 
#include<string.h>
```

More questions plz ask...